# finding partial sum of series with square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, fractions

I'm trying to practice finding formulas of sums (partial sums).
stuck a bit with this sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
$$

the answare should be
$$S_n=\sqrt{n+1}-1$$

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name $n$ for both the dummy variable of the summation and the upper limit.

Comment: @Phisagi Are you sure you copied the problem correctly? I strongly suspect it should be 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \color{red}{-} \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect there to be a closed form for the partial sum?

Comment: yes @BenGrossmann I agree that this looks more reasonable (as a telescopic sum)
but I typed correctly. I'm attaching pic of the whole question https://ibb.co/ZHgVMfL

edit:i see i mistyped the plus sign in the middle, now its the right one

Comment: @Phisagi Have you tried to rationalize the denominator?

Comment: The upper limit of the sum in the image is $\infty$, not $n$. So what Robert is pointing out is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the sum in a more managable way we have:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^k\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^k\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^k{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}
\end{equation}
Now:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^k{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2}-1+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}+\ldots+\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}= \sqrt{k+1}-1
\end{equation}
The series does not converge as $\displaystyle{\lim_{k \to +\infty} S_k= +\infty}$.
You can see that it diverges also using asymptotic behaviour:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\sim \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much!! made it glass clear :)

Comment: Just need practice, keep going mate!